# All third-party repositories failing to update (Launchpad and Google, especially)

Tags: updates, repository

Just something that started today, Ubuntu repos have been extremely slow...

I can't even reliably `apt-get update` but I solved that by [changing the update server](http://blog.hafees.com/linux/ubuntu-change-download-server-and-fix-slow-updates/), ironically, now I'm realizing all third-party repos are extremely slow or timing out and failing.

Anyone else experiencing this? Any suggestions for fixing it? I am a third-party repo addict so I have quite a few: all launchpad repos failing, google's, and others.

**EDIT**:
I've [reported here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=93409) concerning Google, not sure where to post for Launchpad.

I will add, it is hit or miss, I was able to hit launchpad a bit.

So my question really is: Any launchpad alternatives like there are for changing official update servers as posted above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any launchpad alternatives like there are for changing official update servers as posted above?

No, PPAs are hosted only on launchpad.net and are not mirrored. I usually find launchpad.net to be slower than any local mirror for the official repositories.